# How to use canvas to modify images from another domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

This is the code i am using when i have `image.src = "/local/directory/image.png"` works but if i use `image.src="http://remote/path"` it loads the image but rest mousemove function do not work. How do you fix it?

**copy and paste to test.htm**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var image = new Image();
  var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
  image.src = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
  //image.src = "/agents/google.png";

  image.width="340";
  image.height="220";
  image.onload = function () 
  {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
  }
  $('#canvas').mousemove(function(e) 
  { 
    var canvasOffset = $(this).offset();
    var canvasX = Math.floor(e.pageX - canvasOffset.left);
    var canvasY = Math.floor(e.pageY - canvasOffset.top);
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(canvasX, canvasY, 1, 1);
    var pixel = imageData.data;

    var pixelColor = "rgba("+pixel[0]+", "+pixel[1]+", "+pixel[2]+", "+pixel[3]+")";
    $(document.body).css('background-color',pixelColor);

  });

});
</script>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="340" height="220"></canvas>
<body>
```

Follow up (copy paste):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/betamax/getImageData/master/jquery.getimagedata.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  //  var image = new Image();
  //  var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
  //  //image.src = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
  //  image.src = "/agents/google.png";
  //  
  //  image.width="340";
  //  image.height="220";
  //  image.onload = function () 
  //  {
  //    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
  //  }
  //  $('#canvas').mousemove(function(e) 
  //  { 
  //    var canvasOffset = $(this).offset();
  //    var canvasX = Math.floor(e.pageX - canvasOffset.left);
  //    var canvasY = Math.floor(e.pageY - canvasOffset.top);
  //    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(canvasX, canvasY, 1, 1);
  //    var pixel = imageData.data;
  //
  //    var pixelColor = "rgba("+pixel[0]+", "+pixel[1]+", "+pixel[2]+", "+pixel[3]+")";
  //    $(document.body).css('background-color',pixelColor);
  //
  //  });
  $.getImageData({
    url: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png",
    success: function(image){
   
      // Set up the canvas
      var can = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
      var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
   
      // Set the canvas width and heigh to the same as the image
      $(can).attr('width', image.width);
      $(can).attr('height', image.height);
   
      // Draw the image on to the canvas
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
   
      // Get the image data
      var image_data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0,  image.width, image.height);
      var image_data_array = image_data.data;
   
      // Invert every pixel
      //for (var i = 0, j = image_data_array.length; i < j; i+=4) {
      //image_data_array[i] = 255 - image_data_array[i];
      //image_data_array[i+1] = 255 - image_data_array[i+1];
      //image_data_array[i+2] = 255 - image_data_array[i+2];
      //}
   
      // Write the image data to the canvas
      ctx.putImageData(image_data, 0, 0);

      $('#canvas').mousemove(function(e) 
      { 
        var canvasOffset = $(this).offset();
        var canvasX = Math.floor(e.pageX - canvasOffset.left);
        var canvasY = Math.floor(e.pageY - canvasOffset.top);
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(canvasX, canvasY, 1, 1);
        var pixel = imageData.data;

        var pixelColor = "rgba("+pixel[0]+", "+pixel[1]+", "+pixel[2]+", "+pixel[3]+")";
        $(document.body).css('background-color',pixelColor);

      });
   
    },
    error: function(xhr, text_status){
      // Handle your error here
    }
  });

});
</script>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="340" height="220"></canvas>
<body>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to directly read an image from another domain.

However, manipulate images from another domain can be achieved by getting a **base-64** string interpretation of the image, and use it.

This feature is implemented in jQuery by the `$.imagedata` plugin, which can be downloaded at **[this site](http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/#download)**.

Comment: If you can just do this, why does the spec bother with preventing the same behavior using getImageData?

Comment: Web in high level or senior level. Makes no sense with those nonsense security excuses. There are lot of reason i needed this feature. But alas HTML5 is back to 1970's still. I have to follow Rob W advise finally.

Comment: Directy modifying images from other domains can be a security issue. Behind the scenes (at the plugin), a call is made to an external server. This server loads the external image, and converts it to a base-64 string. Then, the result is returned as a base-64-data-URL, which can be assigned to the `src` attribute. Since the image is created at the current page, it does not suffer from a *Same Origin Policy*, or something similar.

Comment: Nevermind - the link you've posted requires a backend, which makes sense. Edit: you beat me to it. That makes sense though. Also @Google  it appears you do not understand why this is restricted. Please read through our comments and read the spec so you understand _why_ it is restricted. It is to protect the user not to inconvenience developers.

Comment: @Cam The back-end is already provided. See the bottom of the linked page for an example to use the feature without jQuery. **Also, example URL**: http://img-to-json.appspot.com/?url=http://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico

Comment: @Rob W: Right - I was just indicating that it proxies through a server (whether you provide your own or not) which makes sense because then there are no client-side security concerns.

Comment: I followed this method. But its slow. 1) Serer download 60 frames per seconds in server 2) Viewer download from server 60 frames per second i have lip sync issue.

Comment: @Google: The reason it is slow is because it uses an external sever as part of the process. Again, I **highly encourage** you to use a  different environment. Even if it has to be done in a browser, perhaps use some other technology (java, flash, etc).

Comment: Thanks edited above. Works i can move forward with this. Thanks a lot Rob W.

Comment: Not working: http://img-to-json.appspot.com/ "This application is temporarily over its serving quota. Please try again later." Not a reliable solution...

Comment: @NickWiggill Try to use https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com as CORS proxy. If you wish, you can self-host this proxy, its source code is available at https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere

Answer (score 1):

According to the [specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html) you cannot use getImageData when the source of the canvas is coming from an external URL.

From the specs:

> Whenever the getImageData() method of the 2D context of a canvas
>   element whose origin-clean flag is set to false is called with
>   otherwise correct arguments, the method must throw a SecurityError
>   exception.

Comment: but i need to scan from scanner which is located in remote as http://randomIP/directory/scaner.jpeg?<randomnumbers>

Comment: Is randomIP the same location as the server you are running the core code from? If not... this isn't possible. You may consider using a PHP proxy to download the image to the server first then accessing it through a local relative path.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons you cannot use getImageData when the image is external. Read [this article](http://blog.project-sierra.de/archives/1577) for more information.

Depending on your browser, if you run the code locally with a local image you may also get an error.

However if you use this code on a server and access it via a domain name *and* the image is hosted on the same server, the code will work fine.

**Edit**:

> but i need to scan from scanner which is located in remote as randomIP/directory/scaner.jpeg?

Then maybe your solution should not involve client-side, in-browser JS. Can you not use another language like PHP that doesn't have these sorts of restrictions? Or why not use JS under a different environment that doesn't restrict you the way browsers do?

I recommend PHP because it's easy to use and has the GD library.

Comment: Assuming the code is also running on remoteip I would expect it to work fine.

Comment: When i use remoteIP anything except local directory path. Does not work i have tried several times like 60 times with 60 different url + different ip's.

Comment: It will only work if the image *and* the code are located on the same domain.

Comment: Thats a BUG. (i have 50 remote locations, and it has realtime scanner jpeg).

Comment: It is not a bug. It is part of the javascript spec, and it is like this due to security reasons. It would be insecure if client-side javascript were allowed to do this. For example suppose facebook profile images are located at facebook.com/profile.jpg when the user is logged in. If you were on my site I could load in profile.jpg in the background, scan it using imageData and send the information to my server. Obviously this is problematic so the spec does not allow you to do this.

Comment: For Facebook or Google a Universal language should not make a stupid protection. In my case, i have realtime devices where i have web wall. And i need to rescan realtime. From remote IP (20/30/60 frames per seconds).

Comment: It's better to inconvenience a couple of developers such as yourself than to make the web insecure for every user! Use a different language, or use JS in a less-restrictive environment (not in a browser). Or use Rob W's solution. There are many options but the code you've posted is bug-free - it simply doesn't work due to a browser security restriction.