# how to replace/mask specific colors as web image (non-local) loads?

Tags: javascript, html, image, colors

Here is what I like to do. Let's say I'm loading an image from example.com/test.png on browser and image is not saved on local server. Then, I like to detect blue color in the image and replace/mask the it with red color. In other words, colors appear differently when they load. Is this pratical using javascript, html, ...or any other way?

If image was local, we could use color detection codes and create new image with modified color. However, in real time image loading, the process seems different. I appreciate if anyone can direct me to any api, sample codes, readings,...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [CSS3 Filters](http://davidwalsh.name/css-filters) - specifically the `hue()` property. Maybe not as precise as you're looking for though, taking a specific pixel hue and changing it conditionally.

Alternatively, you could load the image into a `<canvas>` tag where you can do whatever you want with it, although there are [certain restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7988342/752213) to consider.

Comment: The thing is, not all browsers support CSS3 and although, hue() function is good but to specific enough. Plus, image is not on my server and the best case is to somehow duplicate the image and apply changes to that Nevertheless, thanks for ur suggestion