# How to download a leaflet image of a map with a layer

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

I'm trying to get a snapshot using `leaflet-image` plugin. 
I'm getting this error:

`leaflet-image.js:195 Element could not be drawn on canvas <svg class=​"leaflet-zoom-animated" width=​"1220" height=​"790" viewBox=​"-24 -16 1220 790" style=​"transform:​ translate3d(-24px, -16px, 0px)​;​">​…​</svg>​handlePathRoot @ leaflet-image.js:195start @ leaflet-image.js:336poke @ leaflet-image.js:324(anonymous function) @ leaflet-image.js:352tileQueueFinish @ leaflet-image.js:172maybeNotify @ leaflet-image.js:377(anonymous function) @ leaflet-image.js:353im.onload @ leaflet-image.js:148`

It's happening when I load a layer to the map ([as the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1ieZ.jpg))

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to create a jsFiddle that reproduces this, image is not enough to debug your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that the image does not have CORS headers, and the `<canvas>` HTML element that `leaflet-image.js` uses is being tainted.

This problem is well documented in the questions: [«Cross-origin data in HTML5 canvas»](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972049/cross-origin-data-in-html5-canvas#11285847) and [«Canvas image crossplatform insecure error»](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743987/canvas-image-crossplatform-insecure-error). Ultimately you'll have to make sure that CORS is enabled in the web server that you're fetching the image from.